# unable to get letest data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get web data using IMPORTXML function in Google spreadsheet.
It is working first time only thereafter it does not get the newest data and returns me previous data only.

I tried by creating a different sheet, different websites but getting the same issue. Even I paste directly formula

```
=IMPORTXML("https://money.cnn.com/data/us_markets/","(//div[@class='bannerQuote']/span)[2]")
```

into cell still, it works only the first time then it returns me old value.

```
  function f1() {
var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
var queryString = Math.random(); 
var xpaths = "//span[@id='ct']";
var cellFunction = '=IMPORTXML("https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/india","'+xpaths+'")';
var cell1= sheetName.getRange("A5");
cell1.clearContent();
sheetName.getRange('A5').setValue(cellFunction); 
var xpaths1 ="(//div[@class='bannerQuote']/span)[2]";
var cellFunction1 = '=IMPORTXML("https://money.cnn.com/data/us_markets","'+xpaths1+'")';
sheetName.getRange('A6').setValue(cellFunction1); 
}
```

Comment: Welcome. It's not clear how is the code is being used and that you already reviewed the related documentation. Are you aware that IMPORTXML as well as other IMPORT functions are recalculated at certain time intervals and not every time that the spreadsheet is recalculated?

Answer (score 0):

Google caches the results for about two hours for the same URL, so you need to add a fragment identifier (#) with a random number to the URL, like this:

```
function f1() {
  var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
  var queryString = Math.round(Math.random()*100000); 
  var xpaths = "//span[@id='ct']";
  var cellFunction = '=IMPORTXML("https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/india#' + queryString + '","'+xpaths+'")';
  var cell1= sheetName.getRange("A5");
  cell1.clearContent();
  sheetName.getRange('A5').setValue(cellFunction); 
  var xpaths1 ="(//div[@class='bannerQuote']/span)[2]";
  var cellFunction1 = '=IMPORTXML("https://money.cnn.com/data/us_markets#' + queryString + '","' + xpaths1+'")';
  sheetName.getRange('A6').setValue(cellFunction1); 
}
```

This way the URL you use will be different each time.